# Strange Behavior Between ListCollectionView.Refresh() and RoutedCommand

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListView` which is bound to a `ListCollectionView`.

In the same window I have a `Button` with an attached `RoutedCommand` with no `CanExecute` handler.

```
    public static RoutedCommand RefreshCommand = new RoutedCommand();

<CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:DatabaseTaskViewer.RefreshCommand}"Executed="RefreshCommandExecuted"/>

<Button Command="{x:Static local:DatabaseTaskViewer.RefreshCommand}">Refresh</Button>



private void RefreshCommandExecuted(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Presenter.Process();
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

The problem is that whenever I do a `ListCollectionView.Refresh()` to apply a new filter to my collection, the `Button` gets disabled... until I click on a row in my `ListView`!

I isolated the problem between the `Refresh()` and the `RoutedCommand` (if I exclude the command from the `Button` it stays enabled).

Have you heard something similar before? Do you have any idea what to do?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: pls show us how RefreshCommand is contruction, is it inheriting from ICommand ? if so, try implementing CanExecute and return true by default

Comment: @anvarbek Thanks for your reply. RefreshCommand is a RoutedCommand derived from ICommand. I already tried what you suggest with CanExecute... no luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give up... I will go for the `RelayCommand` solution...

Thanks everyone who tried to help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check your RefreshCommandExecuted, you somehow affect Command's Enable state.
Regards.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I just added the code for the RefreshCommandExecuted. As you can see nothing strange is in there. By the way the Refresh() is not called from the button but from a set property of my view model.

Comment: not sure why you are using {x:Static} static extension, if you RefreshCommand  is in the ViewModel, then you should simply say  {Binding RefreshCommand} in your button and it will pick it up from the DataContext

Answer (score 0):

Try setting command target to its parent. 
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc785480.aspx